# NoClassDefFoundError received when testing with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a test class:

```
package com.souradeep.mockito.scrapbook;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class ATest {

    @Mock
    B b;
    private A a;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        a = new A(b);
    }

    @Test
    public void usesVoidMethod_Should_Call_Void_Method() throws Exception {
        doNothing().when(b).voidMethod();
        assertEquals(1, a.usesVoidMethod());
        verify(b).voidMethod();
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void usesVoidMethod_Should_Throw_Runtime_Exception() throws Exception {
        doThrow(Exception.class).when(b).voidMethod();
        a.usesVoidMethod();
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testConsecutiveCalls() throws Exception {
        doNothing().doThrow(Exception.class).when(b).voidMethod();
        a.usesVoidMethod();
        verify(b).voidMethod();
        a.usesVoidMethod();
    }
}
```

Here I am mocking class B (please see code below)

```
package com.souradeep.mockito.scrapbook;

public class B {
    public void voidMethod() throws Exception {
        
    }
}
```

I am implementing class A (Please see code below)

```
package com.souradeep.mockito.scrapbook;

public class A {
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int usesVoidMethod() {
        try {
            b.voidMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When trying to run JUnit test I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$3
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:30)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
at com.souradeep.mockito.scrapbook.ATest.setup(ATest.java:19)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

The error is coming at the line

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Please assist as to what could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error while trying to upgrade java 8 -> 17

I fixed it by updating mockito 1 -> 3